# Get newsfeed with Facebook GraphApi in iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

I need to view the facebook newsfeeds in my UITableView. I send an asynchronous request to the server and I have obtained the list of newsfeeds. The problem is that i do not obtain, for each feed, the size of the image, and so I must send another asynchronous request to the server nested to previous asynchronous request. This code is very low efficent because I must reload my UITableView repeatedly (see my code).

I need get the image size so as set the height of the UITableCell and the dimension of UIImageView inside the cell.

Any idea to solve my problem ?

Below my code:

```
-(void)loadData{

    //self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    self.imgDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    self.desArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.mexArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.udidArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/guide/feed" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error){
        NSDictionary *data = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

        for(NSDictionary *dic in data) {

            if([dic objectForKey:@"description"]==nil){
                [self.desArr addObject:@""];
            }else{
                [self.desArr addObject:[dic objectForKey:@"description"]];
            }


            if([dic objectForKey:@"object_id"]==nil){
                [self.udidArr addObject:@""];
            }else{
                [self.udidArr addObject:[dic objectForKey:@"object_id"]];
                [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[dic objectForKey:@"object_id"]] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error) {
                    [self.imgDic setObject:[result objectForKey:@"images"] forKey:[result objectForKey:@"id"]];
                    //NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]);
                    //NSLog(@"%@",[result objectForKey:@"images"]);
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                 }];
            }

            if([dic objectForKey:@"message"]==nil){
              [self.mexArr addObject:@""];
            }else{
              [self.mexArr addObject:[dic objectForKey:@"message"]];
            }


        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];

     }];


}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self loadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way using /me/feed, however you could use a [Batch Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) to get all the data at once.

Something like this, sent to https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/ in the `batch` parameter should return the size of the images.

```
[
    {
        "method": "GET",
        "name": "get-feed",
        "relative_url": "me/feed"
    },
    {
        "method": "GET",
        "relative_url": "?ids={result=get-feed:$.data.*.object_id}"
    }
]
```